Disable logging in APIM for certain endpoints in APIM
Their are some sensitive APIs that are onboarded on APIM and i want no logging to be done for them due to security concerns.
Was able to get many things but none of them work and was not in the will to make custom appsinsights to be done so it just reject those logs is that the only way to not log few apis.
Have tried multiple policy both global and api level none worked till now

Can you please share what you have tried ?

have tried global policy using the event hub method but did not work was also trying to dynamically manage application insights from 100% to 0% but was not able to do

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.



<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path.Contains("/specific-endpoint"))">
            <set-variable name="disableLogging" value="true" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <set-variable name="disableLogging" value="false" />
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
    <log-to-eventhub logger-id="your-eventhub-logger-id" />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("disableLogging") == false)">
            <!-- Include logging policy here -->
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>



APIM policies allow you to define how your APIs are processed. You can use policies to enable or disable logging dynamically. Here's an example of how you can control logging with policies:

Go to your API in the APIM portal.
Select the Design tab.
Choose the operation you want to configure or apply a policy at the API level if it’s for multiple operations.
Select Inbound processing or Outbound processing, depending on where you want to apply the policy.
To disable logging for specific endpoints, you would typically use a conditional policy expression. For example:


i Tried this metthod and found out one note in the reference.
The policy is not affected by Application Insights sampling. All invocations of the policy will be logged.
Reference :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/log-to-eventhub-policy
So this will not work as we can still have logs in application insights

Just use the settings option of APIM and set it to 0%

